# Передача кириллицы в чате через сокеты Python

Tags: python, сокет, utf-8

Доброго времени суток! Написан небольшой чат через сокеты, но, получается отправлять только сообщения и ник на латинице. Понял, что нужно использоваться `encode/decode` но не понял где именно.Код прилагаю.`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
from tkinter import *


tk=Tk()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('',9999))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)

text=StringVar()
name=StringVar()
name.set('')
text.set('')
tk.title('Chat')
tk.geometry('400x300')

log = Text(tk)
nick = Entry(tk, textvariable=name)
msg = Entry(tk, textvariable=text)
msg.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
nick.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
log.pack(side='top', fill='both',expand='true')

def loopproc():
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        message = s.recv(60)
        log.insert(END,message+'\n')
    except:
        tk.after(1,loopproc)
        return
    tk.after(1,loopproc)
    return

def sendproc(event):
    sock.sendto (name.get()+':'+text.get(),('255.255.255.255',9999))
    text.set('')

msg.bind('<Return>',sendproc)

tk.after(1,loopproc)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Использовать там, где данные получаете: `s.recv(60)`. А ошибки в `log.insert(END,message+'\n')` возникают? message это тип bytes, а bytes + str не получится сделать

Comment: Нет, это проходит нормально `sock.sendto (nick.get()+':'+text.get().encode('utf-8'),('255.255.255.255',9999))` с кодированием сообщения получилось решить проблему так, но, ник не получится так закодировать, вообще к нику нигде не подобраться с методом encode

Answer (score 1):

Вот так (python3):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
from tkinter import *


tk=Tk()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('',9999))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)

text = StringVar()
name = StringVar()
name.set('')
text.set('')
tk.title('Chat')
tk.geometry('400x300')

log = Text(tk)
nick = Entry(tk, textvariable=name)
msg = Entry(tk, textvariable=text)
msg.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
nick.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
log.pack(side='top', fill='both',expand='true')

def loopproc():
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        bmessage = s.recv(60)
        message = bmessage.decode()
        log.insert(END,message+'\n')
    except:
        tk.after(1,loopproc)
        return
    tk.after(1,loopproc)
    return

def sendproc(event):
    message = '{name}:{text}'.format(name=name.get(), text=text.get())
    bmessage = message.encode()
    sock.sendto(bmessage, ('255.255.255.255', 9999))
    text.set('')

msg.bind('<Return>', sendproc)
```